# git difftool gives strange results with staged and also unstaged changes

Tags: git, diff, meld, git-difftool

`meld` (for example) is selected for git difftool invocation:

```
git config --list | grep diff
```

gives:

```
diff.tool=meld
```

I have one file with only staged changes, and another file with unstaged changes.

When I run `git difftool`, I expect only the unstaged changes to be shown (with meld). But to my surprise, I see that `git diff --cc xxx_file_with_staged_changes_xxx` is invoked, just before the expected meld invocation for the file with only unstaged changes.

Yet, the GIT manual states that:

> git diff [--options] [--] […​] This form is to view the changes
>   you made relative to the index (staging area for the next commit). In
>   other words, the differences are what you could tell Git to further
>   add to the index but you still haven’t. You can stage these changes by
>   using git-add[1].

So only the unstaged changes should be shown, no? And note the strange `git diff` invocation produced by `git difftool` in my case, just before the expected invocation of the "difftool" (here, meld).

Comment: I’m not sure how you see that `git diff --cc` is invoked and why it worries you. In my experiments, `git difftool` only shows unstaged changes, which, I believe, is what you expect too.